# Determining Image Filesize Before Scaling

Tags: android, ios, image, filesize

The the iOS Mail app used to have a handy feature (I believe they removed it with the advent of Mail Drop) that would give you the option to select a scaled version of an image attachment. The great thing about this feature was that it would actually calculate the file size of each of the scaled images; shown below:

[image: iOS Mail Image size activity]

The server I am uploading images to has a small file size limit (10 MB), and I would like to emulate this functionality in order to prevent uploads that exceed this limit.

With the assumption that the image is not actually scaled down three times in order to determine the file size of each of the scaled images; how would I go about doing this?

I have not been able to find any information regarding some type of formula to calculate the file size of a scaled down image based on the size of the original image.

Comment: as bitmap ? yes it's `W * H * bytes_per_pixel` .... in compressed format (png, jpg) the only way is to do the scaling

Comment: @Selvin And the `bytes_per_pixel` depends on the configuration of the bitmap, correct? (i.e. `ARGB_8888`) But the compressed format should be significantly smaller than that calculation, no?

Answer (score 1):

Given the delay i've always seen when I pop that dialog on older devices, which is a non-trivial delay, I challenge your assumption that Apple isn't just doing the dirty-deed here -- ie. writing those JPGs directly to memory/disk and reading the size, rather than calculating this... ie. `let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6)!`

The trick is likely that people are falling down the "it needs to be at least 80% quality to be real!" hole. That's only true if you have a terrible JPG/media library. In reality, if you're writing a reasonably complex UIImage to memory/disk and you don't need transparency, then 60% is plenty.